# Unwanted Attributes Magically Appear

Tags: drupal-7, ubercart

I'm using Ubercart 3.8. I'm trying to modify the customer invoice using the template file uc-order--customer.tpl.php, which is of course in my theme directory. I *know* this is the template for the invoice because I make a minor change to this template and the change shows up on the invoice.

So by default product attributes for all line items in the invoice are printed above the line items, like so:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/49576796/ub_attr.png

My client wants them to appear with the line items. No problem, I say to myself, I'll just edit the template. But in that template, there is *nothing* in the spot where that text is appearing. See below:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/49576796/ub_template_code.png

The attributes are appearing after the BR tag and before the TABLE tag. There is no echo statement, no print statement, nothing at that location. Those attributes are just appearing on the invoice, in that spot, for no reason I can see. And again, I've verified I'm editing the correct template.

Can anyone help me out? Tell me what's going on? Is some hook doing this? Point me to the docs that describe this? I've googled the heck out of this problem and I'm stumped.